# JRuby gem problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, rubygems

I am trying to run a rails application in Netbeans with JRuby as the underlying Ruby. When I try to run the server, I got an error like this,

```
Missing these required gems:
  libxml-ruby
```

So I tried installing the libxml-ruby gem, but I cannot install it because its a native version and jruby would not support it. Thats fine.

```
(in /home/braga/prj/eschool/trunk)
jruby -S gem install libxml-ruby
ERROR:  Error installing libxml-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/home/braga/netbeans-6.9/ruby/jruby-1.5.0/bin/jruby extconf.rb
WARNING: JRuby does not support native extensions or the `mkmf' library.
         Check http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/Home for alternatives.
extconf.rb:23: uninitialized constant CONFIG (NameError)
```

So, I had to install an alternative and I installed the libxml-jruby gem. And I started the server again. But still I am getting the following error,

```
Missing these required gems:
  libxml-ruby
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you have declared `require "libxml-ruby"` some where either in code or the plugin you are using , make sure you have `require "libxml-jruby"` .

Hope this is helpful